# can you find two invertible matrices that satisfy this?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $[A, B] = AB - BA$.  Can you find two invertible $n \times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $[A, B] = AB - BA = E_{ii} - E_{jj}$

Comment: What is $E_{ii}$ supposed to represent? This is non-standard notation.

Comment: @adfriedman $E_{ij}$ is the matrix with one non-zero entry, a $1$ in row $i$ and column $j$. This is pretty standard notation.

Comment: If you need help, it is counter-productive to assume that every student of mathematics knows what some particular notation means. Especially if it takes one sentence to explain it.

Answer (score 3):

**Useful fact**

$$E_{ij}E_{kl}=\delta_{jk}E_{il}$$

where $\delta_{ab}=1$ if $a=b$, $0$ otherwise (Kronecker symbol)

---

If $i=j$ then $A=B=Id$ works.

Otherwise let $A=Id + E_{ij}$ and $B=Id+E_{ji}$.

Then $AB=Id+E_{ij}+E_{ji}+E_{ii}$ and $BA=Id+E_{ij}+E_{ji}+E_{jj}$. You have $AB-BA=E_{ii}-E_{jj}$.

Note that $A$ and $B$ are indeed invertible, because they are elementary matrices associated to row-addition transformations: $A^{-1}=Id-E_{ij}$

Comment: Note that from this calculation, $[x Id + U, x Id + V] = [U, V]$ for all matrices $U, V$ and any scalar $x$. For real or complex matrices, it implies that given $U$ and $V$, there always are invertible matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $[A, B] = [U, V]$.